# jhipster gateway in container can not zuul to microservice running in localhost

Tags: docker, containers, jhipster, gateway

I have a issue, I use jhipster to genrate 3 microservices: gateway, uaa, and gambling-producer.
When I use docker-compose to run 3 services together, it works well then I stop gambling-producer service and run ./mvnw on localhost for this service, it does not work when working together. gateway can not zuul this service

I tried some cases:

- Dont edit any application.yaml, applicaton-dev.yml  config files of 3 services above.
- On gateway applicaton.yml:

```
   routes:
    gamblingproducer:
      url: http://localhost:8081
```

Or

```
 routes:
    gamblingproducer:
      path: services/gamblingproducer/**
      serviceId: gamblingproducer
```

It throws exception: `Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

```
gateway_1  | com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.handleException(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:261)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:241)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
gateway_1  |    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
gateway_1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
gateway_1  |    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:180)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at microservices.gateway.web.filter.RefreshTokenFilter.doFilter(RefreshTokenFilter.java:62)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
gateway_1  |    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
gateway_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
gateway_1  |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
gateway_1  |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
gateway_1  | Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:422)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:341)
gateway_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:236)
gateway_1  |    ... 116 common frames omitted
gateway_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
gateway_1  |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
gateway_1  |    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
gateway_1  |    ... 126 common frames omitted
gateway_1  |
```

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Which service discovery do you use?

Comment: Eureka Clients, bro

Comment: So why do you define static zuul routes? Have you looked your registered eureka clients in the jhipster registry? Have they renewed their leases?

Comment: 1. I define static zuul routers because I see that when service running, it show up local and external. That 's why I wanna try some case
2. All of them are registered
3. Yes, they have
This is my eureka 

`

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/

`
.I am using MacOs.
Thanks

Comment: When I run gambling-producer at localhost using ./mvnw. I saw some things wrong. It is signal not good for deploying and after all it deployed ok
 
`
task supervisor timed out

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
`
....
 But When I switch to this service on swagger, it show messages `ZuulException: Forwarding error ` above

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is always resolved to 127.0.0.1 which is the container itself. Change `localhost` To your host ip or container/service name where eureka is running, but never use localhost. Think of applications in containers as they were running on separated, distant hosts. Never use localhost unless you want to loop back into same container (which almost never happens).

Update:

Basing on the comments section, like I said, the problem is in the "localhost" and the way how it's treated. From what I understand, scenario looks like this: mvnw on host is connecting to eureka in docker saying:"hi, I'm mnvw and you can reach me on localhost:8081". But eureka when trying to verify calls localhost and instead your host it gets eureka' s localhost which is the container. So the solution to your problem is to make mnvw to say the hostname (or ip) where it can be found by eureka container, never localhost. Using localhost is very tricky when it comes to containers, so be aware!

Comment: I knew that. I tried already, but it doesn't work. Ip address  and service name.

Comment: Please post your docker-compose file. Are you running/deplyoing using `docker-compose up` or in docker swarm?

Comment: please see docker-compose file at https://github.com/lebabach/gambling-producer/blob/master/src/main/docker/app_backup.yml

after run docker-compose, you can run ./mvnw from this service on localhost. It does't work when we access from swagger on localhost:8080 (gateway)

Comment: To clarify - mvnw is your app, executed on host (?), that you expect to be discovered by eureka (running in docker, no port exposed), so it can be accessed through gateway running in docker with external port 8080?

Comment: Yes. U got damn right. I am not good at docker deeply. I dont know should I config more at docker compose like expose port blahblah. Please help me. Thank u for reply

Comment: I already export port . the title should be change to Eureka client localhost can not access to Eureka server in docker container, please help me @Miq